# Is there a way to adjust scrollbar-thumb to represent element width (Image Gallery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, image-gallery

I am trying make an image gallery with a slider bar. Mostly with CSS and I'm choosing to use a simple scrollbar as the slider. On mobile I am displaying one image at a time, therefore I have no problems with the scrollbar. However here - the desktop code, I am displaying 3 images at a time (inside viewport I mean) and of course the scrollbar is meant to adapt based on the viewport of the container.

My goal is to make the size of scrollbar-thumb to be represented as one element in the container even if there are more elements in view (in this case 3). However using width property on the thumb does not do anything.

https://codepen.io/eyyminda/pen/wvEgvzQ

`

```
   .container {
      --_spacer: 2vw;
      gap: var(--_spacer);
      grid-auto-columns: 26vw;
      grid-auto-rows: 40vw;
      padding: 0 var(--_spacer);
    }

    .snaps-inline {
      scroll-snap-type: inline mandatory;
      scroll-padding-inline: var(--_spacer, 1rem);
    }

    .snaps-inline>* {
      scroll-snap-align: center;
    }

    div.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
      height: 1.8vw;
    }

    div.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      border-radius: 1vw;
      margin-inline: 5vw;
    }

    div.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      border-radius: 1vw;
      width: calc(100% / 3); /*Does not work*/
    }
```

`

Tried using JS too which also does not work.

Also tested with border-width but that removes border-radius.

It's kind of hard to wrap my head about this. Should I change the width of the container to be the size of one element and let overflow to be visible and then use overflow: hidden on the container of the container?
But that would allow the scroll bar to be used all the way to the start/end therefore bring the first/last image to the center and leaving a gap on either side of the container.

Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Please add a fully running [reprex], because atm we have to construct a page and try to recreate your issue. We need to see the code to find your issue...

Comment: Sorry about that, included the link to codepen